# Do while in SQL procedure, limit by i

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, do-while

i came across a procedure with this code

```
DELIMITER $$
Create PROCEDURE Procedure1 (IN A int)  
BEGIN   
DECLARE n int DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE i int DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE column_int int DEFAULT NULL;

  SELECT
    COUNT(1)
  FROM table1 t1
  WHERE t1.id = A INTO n;

  WHILE i < n DO
    SELECT
      t1.B
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE t1.id = A
    ORDER BY t1.id
    LIMIT i, 1 INTO column_int;

    CALL Procedure2(A, column_int);

    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END
$$
DELIMITER;
```

i don't understand the while part of the code, if we are limiting by i , the first run should give no records ( as i would be 0), and since n will be 1 ( from the first part of the query where count(1) is inserting in n ) how will i<n work ? how will limit i work here ?

Comment: i is being used to set the offset so it stepping through table1 1 row at a time

Answer (score 0):

i is being used to set the offset so it stepping through table1 1 row at a time until i reaches number of rows in table.

the full form of limit is limit offset,number